# Java - Check if array is sorted descendant

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I need to check if array was sorted strictly descendant.
I wrote following code

```
public boolean isSortedDescendant(int [] array){
    if ((array.length == 0) || (array.length == 1)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it not working correctly. for

```
   int[] array2 = {3, 2, 2};
```

at least. I spend a lot of time for different approaches, but without any luck.

Comment: Your code can return true on the first `i` - how do you know the entire array is correct by only checking the first pair?

Comment: Loop is being breaking after first return?

Comment: (The synonym of *descending* is *descendent* (which *is* used where *descendant* may be - word usage is neither reflexive nor transitive).)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should only return true after checking all the pair of elements:

```
public boolean isSortedDescendant(int [] array){
    if ((array.length == 0) || (array.length == 1)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
            if (array[i] <= array[i + 1]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be enough to follow `for (int i = 1 ; i < array.length; i++) if (array[i-1] < array[i]) return false;` with `return true;` (no for explicit special cases or using `else` where `if` always `return`s).

Comment: Thanks. but need little fix  if (array[i] <= array[i + 1]) {

Comment: (Oops - just noted `strictly` in the question: "we" need to include equality as a reason to return `false`.)